# Connect to a WCF Webservice though reporting services, Windows Authentication only?

Tags: wcf, reporting-services, basic-authentication, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to connect to a WCF Webservice using **basic authentication** through SSRS 2008 R2, but all I get is an error complaining that I should be using Windows Authentication.

Is it really the only way to do it? I can't find any official document where this limitation is mentioned.

Can you think of any workaround for this case? (Other than switching to windows authentication).

Thanks for your time.
Regards.

Comment: What does the service configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to connect to the SSRS webService?

If yes, this is a SSRS configuration. You must open the RSReportServer.config file and edit the  tag

more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281310%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)